# LayoutParams require API 19?

Tags: java, android, admob, andengine

I am using Andengine and want to add a Admob banner. I found this code and it is working good. But with this code, the LayoutParams requires API 19 as minimum. I want to be be lower, like say 8 or something like that. What can I use instead?

```
@Override protected void onSetContentView() {
    // CREATING the parent FrameLayout //
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

    // CREATING the layout parameters, fill the screen //
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    // CREATING a Smart Banner View //
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2181015300018417/9550656088");

    // Doing something I'm not 100% sure on, but guessing by the name //
    adView.refreshDrawableState();
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);

    // ADVIEW layout, show at the bottom of the screen //
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                         Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM);

    // REQUEST an ad (Test ad) //
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("AB38B36BA72798C94A9C9329007FD4B0")
    .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // RENDER the add on top of the scene //
    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, this);

    // SURFACE layout ? //
    final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

    // ADD the surface view and adView to the frame //
    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);

    // SHOW AD //
    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
```

} // End of onSetContentView() //

Comment: read the doc. only 1 constructor is api19, all the rest is api 1. you probably don't really need that constructor.

Comment: according to documentation it doesn't require api 19. Only one constructor requires api 19 , just use another one.

Comment: I used another one and now its working great. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that FrameLayout.LayoutParams constructor 
doesn`t support
another FrameLayout as a parameter until the **api 19**.

however there are  another two signature:

public FrameLayout.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams source) - **api 1**

public FrameLayout.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams source) - **api 1**

FrameLayout.LayoutParams is  ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams subclass

so after check that the parameter layout is FrameLayout.LayoutParams

you can solve the problem  as below :

```
        if(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams() instanceOf FrameLayout.LayoutParams){

         final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
                    new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());
    }
```

**The difference beetween the first signature (API 19) 
and others
is that the new LayoutParams object won't have gravity setted**

```
 if(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams() instanceOf FrameLayout.LayoutParams){


    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams paramLP=(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams();

    int gravityHolder=((FrameLayout.LayoutParams)super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams()).gravity;


             final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
                        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(paramLP);

    surfaceViewLayoutParams.gravity=gravityHolder;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());
```

My work around is as below:

```
final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
surfaceViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Seems working for Android Studio + Andengine, API19 not necessary.